# Program freezes trying to read subprocess' stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I have some program, which makes screenshots and uploads them to some server, printing link to that ss afterwards.

Output is like that:

```
######################################################################## 100,0%
https://puu.sh/vcE2l/533ecb687d.png
```

- First line behaves like an loading bar and it uses stderr stream.
- Second line is stdout with that link I like to retrieve.

So I'm writing script like:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['puush', '-a'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Script freezes on communicate(), even if the puush program terminates normally when I use it from terminal.

When I do:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['puush', '-a'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
print('Here')
```

I see process is being terminated normally.

I would be very thankful if somebody could give me a hint.

Comment: I would have said that the `p.wait()` approach is more deadlock-prone, because you're using PIPE for both stdout & stderr. Do you really need to get the standard output & error, and on separate streams? have you tried `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` or `subprocess.DEVNULL` to ignore output ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I deleted PIPE for stderr, but script still freezes on `out, _ = p.communicate()`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'll try that solution in a sec

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Unfortunately passing `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` haven't changed anything

Comment: Do you want to retrieve standard output and not standard error?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I want to get stdout only

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh I see its not a Python problem. It's about weirdness of that program.

Comment: probably. But weirdness calls for workarounds :) check my answer and tell me if it works for you. Obviously I cannot test that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre When i do from terminal `puush -a 1>file` there is nothing in file, stderr is being printed on the screen. When I do `puush -a 2> file`, stdout is being printed on the screen, loading bar is in file. I am clueless

Comment: maybe you can use `os.system("puush -a 1>file")` and read back the file. It sucks, but it could work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre When I do `puush -a 1>file` link is disappearing from terminal, and file is empty too. I straced it, but I'm not really used to reading system calls (Program does a lot of them)

Comment: `"https://puu.sh/vcIxD/c47cb17435."..., 128) = 35` There is a line like that in strace, so program has link in some point